# Twilio conferences: difference between ConferenceTrim and Trim

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-node, twilio-conference

When I add participant to conference programmatically, I can see "ConferenceTrim" and "Trim" attributes in request at Twilio Console.
What is the purpose of them, and what is the difference.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `trim` is used and defined as below for the Conference Noun.

[trim](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference#attributes-trim)

> The trim attribute lets you specify whether to trim leading and
> trailing silence from your audio files. trim defaults to trim-silence,
> which removes any silence at the beginning or end of your recording.
> This may cause the duration of the recording to be slightly less than
> the duration of the call.

`conferenceTrim` is defined for the [REST Participants Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource).

> Whether to trim leading and trailing silence from your recorded
> conference audio files. Can be: trim-silence or do-not-trim and
> defaults to trim-silence.